# "A build function returned null" error when use FutureBuilder to build a listview in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use FutureBuilder to build a listView, however when I run the application, there raises an error which says: A build function returned null.

The data I need is a list, and I want to load it from the local database firstly, if it fails, then I will make a request and get the result from the network. The code is as follows:

```
class AllConferencesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AllConferencesState createState() => new AllConferencesState();
}

class AllConferencesState extends State<AllConferencesPage> {
  List<Conference> _conferences;

  Future _future;

  Future<List<Conference>> loadConferencesFromDatabase() async {

    List<Conference> conferences;

    conferences = await ConferenceProvider.instance.getConferences('1 = 1');

    await ConferenceProvider.instance.close();

    return conferences;
  }

  Future<List<Conference>> loadConferencesFromNetworkResponse(
      Response response) async {
    List<Conference> conferences = new List();
    // ...
    return conferences;
  }

  Future<List<Conference>> loadConferences() async {

    _future = loadConferencesFromDatabase();

    _future.timeout(Duration(seconds: 3),
    onTimeout: () async {
      Response response = await Dio().get(urlPrefix);
      _future = loadConferencesFromNetworkResponse(response);
    });

    return _future;
  }

  Widget _buildConferences(List<Conference> conferences) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: conferences.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return _buildCard(conferences[i]);
      },
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBlank() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _future = loadConferences();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello Flutter'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Conference>>(
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Conference>> snap) {
            if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none || snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return _buildBlank();
            } else if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snap.hasError) {
                return _buildBlank();
              } else if (snap.hasData) {
                if (snap.data != null) {
                  _conferences = snap.data;
                  return _buildConferences(_conferences);
                } else {
                  return _buildBlank();
                }
              }
            }
          },
          future: _future,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have to return with something in the builder function.

Just add the `else` case and return a `Container()` or a `Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())`

EDIT:

```dart
            if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none || snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return _buildBlank();
            } else if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snap.hasError) {
                return _buildBlank();
              } else if (snap.hasData) { // hasData implies data is not null
                _conferences = snap.data;
                return _buildConferences(_conferences);
              } else {
                  return _buildBlank();
              }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I use a _buildBlank() function which returns a `CircularProgressIndicator` when the connectionState is none or waiting, or when the data is null. Can you tell me where should me add the `else` case?

Comment: If `!hasError && !hasData` you return `null`. `hasData` doc says `Returns whether this snapshot contains a non-null [data] value.`, but you check non null data if `hasData == true`